# How would you print a binary tree by it's rows?

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm new to learning about binary trees. I'm trying to figure out how to print the values of a binary tree by it's rows.

Example:

```
             .-------(098)-------.
      .--(012)--.         .--(402)--.
   (006)     (056)      (256)     (512)
```

Will output:

```
 >98
 >12
 >402
 >6
 >56
 >256
 >512
```

Assume that you are given the root node. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: You need a breadth-first traversal.

Comment: See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/breadth_first_traversal.htm

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically a [**BFS (breadth first search)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) will do the required. Its other name is `level-order-traversal`. The reason why it is called level order traversal is because it traverses the tree `level by level`.

For example in case of your binary tree, the levels are:

```
           .-------(098)-------.                  //level 0
      .--(012)--.         .--(402)--.             //level 1
   (006)     (056)      (256)     (512)           //level 2
```

The other convention is that level starts from 1. Now because `BFS` traverses the tree `level by level`

```
First 098 is visited and we are done with level 0

Then 012 and 402 is visited and we are done with level 1

Then 006 , 056 , 256 , 512 are visited and we are done with level 2
```

`BFS` is not only meant for binary trees, its basically a [**graph traversal algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal), and because a tree is nothing but a graph **that is connected with no cycle**, we can use it for tree as well.

Depending on the data structure used the time and space complexity varies:

If [**adjacency matrix**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/) is used to represent the graph then:

Time complexity: **O(V^2)** and 
Space complexity : **O(V^2)**

If [**adjacency list**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/) is used to represent the graph then:

Time complexity: **O(V + E)** and 
Space complexity : **O(V + E)**

Following is BFS pseudocode that can be easily converted to code:

```
BFS(source vertex v)
{
 Enque(v)
 Mark v as visited.
 While(Q is not empty)
  {
    Vertex v’ = deque(Q)
    For all adjacent vertices of v’ that are not visited
     {  Enque them and mark them as visited  }
    We are done with vertex v’
  }
}
```